# javascript form validation for empty field and wrong input

Tags: javascript

this program runs correctly.. my task is, when name field left empty then (please enter your name )this error will be generated and when i type wrong input(like numbers)then (only alphabets and white space are allowed)this error message has to be generate. how can i do this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Validation tutorial</title>
<script>
function validateName(x){
  // Validation rule

  var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;
  // Check input
  if(re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)){
    // Style green
    document.getElementById(x).style.borderColor ='#3BFF3B';
    // Hide error prompt
    document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  }else{
    // Style red
    document.getElementById(x).style.borderColor ='#FF0000';
    // Show error prompt
     document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
    return false; 
  }
 }
 // Validate email
function validateEmail(email){ 
  var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if(re.test(email)){
    document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor ='#3BFF3B';
    document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  }else{
    document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor ='#FF0000';
    return false;
  }
 }
 // Validate Select boxes
 function validateSelect(x){
  if(document.getElementById(x).selectedIndex !== 0){
    document.getElementById(x).style.borderColor ='#3BFF3B';
    document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
    return true;
    }else{
    document.getElementById(x).style.borderColor ='#FF0000';
    return false; 
  }
}
function validateRadio(x){
  if(document.getElementById(x).checked){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
function validateCheckbox(x){
  if(document.getElementById(x).checked){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}   
function validateForm(){
  // Set error catcher
  var error = 0;
  // Check name
   if(!validateName('name')){
    document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "block";
    error++;
  }
  // Validate email
  if(!validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value)){
    document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "block";
    error++;
  }
  // Validate animal dropdown box
  if(!validateSelect('subject')){
    document.getElementById('subjectError').style.display = "block";
    error++;
  }
  // Validate Radio
  if(validateRadio('male')){

  }else if(validateRadio('female')){

  }else{
    document.getElementById('genderError').style.display = "block";
    error++;
  }

  // Don't submit form if there are errors
  if(error > 0){
    return false;
  }
  }     
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onblur="validateName(name)" />
  <span id="nameError" style="display: none;">only alphabates and white space are allowed</span>
    <br><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="validateEmail(value)" />
  <span id="emailError" style="display: none;">You must enter a valid email address</span>
<br><br>

  <label for="hand">Gender</label>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" onblur="validateRadio(id)" />
      <label for="left">male</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" onblur="validateRadio(id)" />
      <label for="right">female</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="validateError" id="genderError" style="display: none;">Please select gender</span>
<br><br>
 <label for="subject">Favourite Subject</label>
  <select name="subject" id="subject" onblur="validateSelect(name)">
    <option value="">SUBJECTS</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="java">JAVA</option>
    <option value="sql">SQL</option>
  </select>
  <span class="validateError" id="subjectError" style="display: none;">You must select your favourite subject</span>
    <br><br>

  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Do some research before asking a question that has been answered a million times. [Check Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) there is a easy example, and all I did was search.

Comment: no this is not related to php

Comment: @Theunis  i researched on all of this but i am new in javascript so thats why ask this qustion.. if you know answer then reply me.. its urgent..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Validation tutorial</title>
<script>
function validateName(x){
  // Validation rule

  var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;
  // Check input
  if(re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)){
    // Style green
    document.getElementById(x).style.borderColor ='#3BFF3B';
    // Hide error prompt
    document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  }else if(document.getElementById(x).value === ''){
    //This is for an empty string or if name was not entered.
    // Style red
    document.getElementById(x).style.borderColor ='#FF0000';
    // Show error prompt
     document.getElementById(x + 'Error2').style.display = "block";
    return false; 
   }else{
    // Style red
    document.getElementById(x).style.borderColor ='#FF0000';
    // Show error prompt
     document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
    return false; 
  }
 }
 // Validate email
function validateEmail(email){ 
  var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if(re.test(email)){
    document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor ='#3BFF3B';
    document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  }else{
    document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor ='#FF0000';
    return false;
  }
 }
 // Validate Select boxes
 function validateSelect(x){
  if(document.getElementById(x).selectedIndex !== 0){
    document.getElementById(x).style.borderColor ='#3BFF3B';
    document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
    return true;
    }else{
    document.getElementById(x).style.borderColor ='#FF0000';
    return false; 
  }
}
function validateRadio(x){
  if(document.getElementById(x).checked){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
function validateCheckbox(x){
  if(document.getElementById(x).checked){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}   
function validateForm(){
  // Set error catcher
  var error = 0;
  // Check name
   if(!validateName('name')){
    document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "block";
    error++;
  }
  // Validate email
  if(!validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value)){
    document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "block";
    error++;
  }
  // Validate animal dropdown box
  if(!validateSelect('subject')){
    document.getElementById('subjectError').style.display = "block";
    error++;
  }
  // Validate Radio
  if(validateRadio('male')){

  }else if(validateRadio('female')){

  }else{
    document.getElementById('genderError').style.display = "block";
    error++;
  }

  // Don't submit form if there are errors
  if(error > 0){
    return false;
  }
  }     
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onblur="validateName(name)" />
  <span id="nameError" style="display: none;">only alphabates and white    space are allowed</span>
 <span id="nameError2" style="display: none;">please enter a name</span>
    <br><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="validateEmail(value)" />
  <span id="emailError" style="display: none;">You must enter a valid email address</span>
<br><br>

  <label for="hand">Gender</label>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" onblur="validateRadio(id)" />
      <label for="left">male</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" onblur="validateRadio(id)" />
      <label for="right">female</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="validateError" id="genderError" style="display: none;">Please select gender</span>
<br><br>
 <label for="subject">Favourite Subject</label>
  <select name="subject" id="subject" onblur="validateSelect(name)">
    <option value="">SUBJECTS</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="java">JAVA</option>
    <option value="sql">SQL</option>
  </select>
  <span class="validateError" id="subjectError" style="display: none;">You must select your favourite subject</span>
    <br><br>

  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

There are much better ways to do this. This is not an elegant way. I see this code is from an example or tutorial. Please check other tutorials on this subject, as this is just a quick way of implementing what you want.

Comment: yes this is from one tutorial.. as you say i will check for other tutorial..  is there any site or tutorial u konw?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) one out